# im trying to download the ubuntu update but it stops mid way and it says failed to download repository information

Tags: support

Im trying to download the Ubuntu update but it stops mid way and it says ''failed to download repository information''.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try running the software updater through the terminal rather than opening the program. It worked for me.

Comment: how do i do that ? im new to ubuntu.

Comment: Open a terminal with ctrl+alt+t. Type `sudo apt-get update` and press enter. You'll be prompted to enter your password, do so and apt-get should proceed with the update.

Comment: That didnt work.